# Get a value from a XML in XSL document version 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo, altova

I have one problem. I am writing a table in a PDF document.
I am getting all the right values except one.

I get a value from a XML lets call that for example
Then I need to find that name in the same XML document and take another value from the other place where it appears:

Look at this example XML document:

```
               </Comment>
                   (...)




                  <Comment>
                  </Comment>
```

So I am writing the NAME inside

Need to save that value, find it in Tset node and write the ToolAddr value after the State, Program name and Tool Name in xsl code.

My xsl to show the NAME and want the next cell to show the size finding by the name:

I need this because Tset is a list of all tools, and in Machining i use the tools not for the normal order and may need the tool adress of the tool more than one time...

HELP!!!

Comment: If you are getting all the right values except one, please _share your XSLT stylesheet_. Then it is more likely that you get answers that are immediately useful to you.

Comment: I know how to get the value by the direct way, but i need get it by searching by the name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the question is a bit vague, it is hard to give a precise answer, but it sounds like you could do with using an **xsl:key** to look up the value (or values) you want.

If you want to look up **code** elements but their **product/Name** you could define a key like so:

```
<xsl:key name="lookupcode" match="code" use="following-sibling::product[1]/Name" />
```

So, this matches **code** elements, but allows them to be looked up by the "Name" of first **Product** element that follows it. (Note, if you are actually using namespaces, rememeber to put the relevant prefix before xxx).

Then, for example, to use this key to look up the code of the 'asdf' value, you would do this

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('lookupcode', 'asdf')" />
```

In a slightly more practical example, if you wanted to look up the code for the **NAME** elements under **zzz**, your code might look something like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="zzz/NAME">
    Name: <xsl:value-of select="." />
    code: <xsl:value-of select="key('lookupcode', .)" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

In a slighty more practical example, here is a simple example that outputs an HTML table.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

   <xsl:key name="lookupcode" match="code" use="following-sibling::product[1]/Name" />

   <xsl:template match="yyyy">
      <table>
         <xsl:for-each select="zzz/Name">
            <tr> 
               <td><xsl:value-of select="." /></td>
               <td><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::DATE[1]" /></td>
               <td><xsl:value-of select="key('lookupcode', .)" /></td>
            </tr>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This should be easy enough to convert to output xsl:fo instead. "tr" elements correspond to "fo:table-row" and "td" elements correspond to "fo:table-cell".

Comment: I update the xml and how i want my layout... I need to do a search for the name, using a variable to match the name and get the size value.

Comment: I've amended my answer to explain how it works with your new XML structure.

Comment: Can you help me to implement that at my code... that code was generate by a software that i dont owns, so to change it i need to do in a notepad... -.-

Comment: Cahnged the xml code to be closer of the real one... i cant show the real here... so im using this example...

Comment: I've edited my answer again to work with this latest example.

Comment: One more time i update the code to the real one... i realy need this problem solved...

I trying to use your idea but how can you see this is realy more complex...

if you can help me with my fo:xsl code i will be gratefull

Comment: You can try using a web site like http://pastebin.com/ to paste a full sample of your XML. Also, can you edit your question to improve the formatting, as the XLST seems to have gone. Thank you.